# Filtragem de registros

Tags: mysql

Boa tarde pessoal, tenho o seguinte a seguinte tabela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho o seguinte select:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT `ip` FROM `visualizacoes` WHERE MONTH(data) = MONTH(NOW()) AND id_usuario = :id_usuario"
```

Use o distinct para retorna apenas um registro por ip, mas gostaria de retorna um registro do ip por noticia.

EX: se um determinado ip visualiza o post 1, e depois visualiza o post 2 eu quero que retorne os dois registro.

Mas se ele visualiza o post 1 duas vezes quero que retorne apenas um registro

PS: Ignorem a existência de duas colunas sobre data.

Comment: Da um `group by ip, id_noticia` veja se é o resultado desejado, e tire o distinct.

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu precisava!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como @rray já citou nos comentários, use [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html).

```
SELECT ip, id_noticia
  FROM visualizacoes
 WHERE MONTH(data) = MONTH(NOW()) 
   AND id_usuario = :id_usuario
 GROUP BY ip, id_noticia;
```

Com `GROUP BY` você pode usar **funções de agregação**. Por exemplo, se quiser contar quantas vezes cada IP visitou uma determinada notícia, use a função `COUNT`:

```
SELECT ip, id_noticia, COUNT(*) AS visitas
  FROM visualizacoes
 WHERE MONTH(data) = MONTH(NOW()) 
   AND id_usuario = :id_usuario
 GROUP BY ip, id_noticia;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, ambas funcionaram.